Output mode configuration on GPIOs: When to use push/pull vs open drain?
Hello guys I'm relatively new to Embedded engineering.
I wanted to know if there's any specific rule that experienced embedded engineers use when selecting when to use one of these output configuration modes?
Thanks a lot

They provide the means (sometimes you can turn on only a weak low-side as well as a weak high-side) for these varying output driver configurations for a reason -- to make sure that they don't have to make different parts for differing situations. So you get a Swiss Army Knife output. But that doesn't mean there is a simple bright line to be drawn about what to do. You look at your need, select the output mode, and go for it. If there were a bright line, they would have seen it, documented it well, provide fewer modes for their outputs, and bought themselves less support hassles in the bargain.

It's not a straightforward and solid way to have a rule for all designs. It will be design-specific.
Each configuration has its own benefits and limitations.
Push-pull:

Can source and sink current. Every load has parasitic capacitance. The push-pull helps to turn on/off the load faster.
Consumes more power. It has two transistors on the output. It consumes slightly more power on switching.

Open drain:

It only sinks current. You need to connect the load to the high side. It's usually a resistor. Because of parasitic capacitors, the switching will be slower. To make it faster, you need lower resistors and it will consume more power.
It only needs one transistor on the output. This means the switching inside the chip will take less power.

There are some applications like I2C that you only can use Open Drain as the bus is shared between devices. This way, if multiple devices try to change the state of the bus, nothing gets damaged. The only bad thing would be that the data is disrupted. But if two push-pull outputs are connected to the same bus and they try to set it to different states, it's like creating a short. The chips can damage each other.
The open drain bus like I2C is suitable for speeds under 1MHz. But a push-pull output, with proper consideration, can be used for 100 MHz. For example, the clock of an SPI memory can be more than 100MHz.
A rule of thumb would be, if you have a low-power application with the need for low-speed switching and your load can be connected to the high side, you can use an open drain. If you need something fast and your load either is connected to the high side or the load side, then the push-pull would be the way to go.

I'd disagree with the "power usage" part. Sure, the MCU itself might nned to drive one Transistor less mit since they are all mostly CMOS anyway, current consumption might only bbe an issue at switching frequencies above 1MHz. But on a open collector/open drain output you need to pull down the current from a pull up resistor. And that's definitely more than what switching an output transistor takes.

As I mentioned, the point of view is from inside the chip. Of course, if you add a load, it will consume power.

I'll agree with kruemi, open-drain requires a high-side impedance which in most cases will pass current for the entire time that the signal is low. At <100kHz, that's likely to be way worse than push-pull, in which the only power consumption is momentary shoot-through, and charge/discharge of load capacitance.

You are looking at the configuration that uses a resistor to create High and Low states with an open drain. Take in mind the case where that pullup is the load itself.

In most cases, you want to use push-pull configuration. It's faster and normally has lower current draw over all.
The push-pull (aka totem-pole) output has two transistors the work complementary. When the output is high the upper transistor pulls the output towards Vcc actively. On a low output the lower transistor pulls the output low actively while the high side blocks.
On a Open collector (or open Drain for that matter), you only pull low. To get the signal high you usually have a load that's connected to Vcc (or another voltage if the device permits it) or a pull up resistor.
Push/Pull is faster and is normally what you go for by default.
When to use Oopen Collector?

If several devices should be able to pull a singnal low (some bus systems like I2C but also Reset lines are examples of this)
If you just want to light a LED that is connected to VCC via a resistor by pulling the ouput low (using a push-pull output doesen't hurt there). Same for opto couplers.
If the signal needs to have a different voltage than what your device is powered with. For example controling a 3.3V device from a 5V MCU. Just put the pull-up resistor on 3.3V. In some cases OC outputs can also tolerate higher voltages than Vcc but carefuly study the documentation before doing that.

I hope this clears up the issue a bit...
